# How can i get flutter website docs offline

Tags: flutter, dart, documentation, offline

I want to get the [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs) documentation site offline using [HTTrack](https://flutter.dev/docs) website copier, but I only got the HTML with no CSS, javascript, or design. When I tried other websites it works; is there any other way?

Comment: The source to flutter.dev is in https://github.com/flutter/website

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you may well have the flutter documentation offline. Here is the download link below:

https://api.flutter.dev/offline/flutter.docset.tar.gz

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I don't have access to the internet 24/7 lately. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **latest** official offline documentation for Flutter.

> Stable Channel: https://api.flutter.dev/offline/flutter.docs.zip
>
> Main Channel: https://main-api.flutter.dev/offline/flutter.docs.zip